# Pyspark using databricks DF.write not working

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

```
try:
  dfEntity.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", "table") \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
```

DF.write not working
print("Connector write failed", error)

Comment: Can you share exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

- As you mentioned that you are facing error while  `dataframe.write`.

  You can follow the below way to write dataframe to SQL database

The below is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
jdbcHostname = "dileepsqlserver.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "db02"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase}"
connectionProperties = {
"user": "dilip",
"password": "Welcome@1"
}
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Spark SQL Example") \
.getOrCreate()
data = [Row(id=1, name="Alice", age=28),
Row(id=2, name="Bob", age=22),
Row(id=3, name="Charlie", age=32)]
columns1 = ["id", "name", "age"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns1)
tableName = "PeopleData"
try:
df1.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", jdbcUrl) \
.option("dbtable", tableName) \
.option("user", connectionProperties["user"]) \
.option("password", connectionProperties["password"]) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
except ValueError as error:
print("An error occurred:", str(error))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]